# Laravel 5.3 withCount() nested relation

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

The model structure is as follows

Tutorial -> (hasMany) Chapters -> (hasMany) videos

How can we load number of videos (video_count) from Tutorial Model with laravel 5.3's  withCount() method

I have tried:

```
Tutorial::withCount('chapters')
->withCount('chapters.videos') // this gives error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chapters.videos()
->all();
```

**Edit**

This works, Any Better solution?

```
Tutorial::withCount('chapters')
->with(['chapters' => function($query){
    $query->withCount('videos');
}])
->all();
```

Comment: Have you define relationship in models?

Comment: You only need to do one ->withCount('chapters.videos'). Also, make sure your relationships are set properly.

Comment: @DigitalFire Relationships are correct as i can load them with eager loading. just count doesn't populates with withCount() method

Comment: Please post your *edit* in answers section. I just prefer to do that.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can only do a `withCount()` on a defined relation of the model.

However, a relationship can be `hasManyThrough` which would achieve what you are after.

```
class Tutorial extends Model
{
    function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chapter');
    }

    function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Video', 'App\Chapter');
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
Tutorial::withCount(['chapters', 'videos'])
```

Docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through