# Laravel Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::post_images()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying this Query in Laravel 5.2

```
User::with(['posts'])
  ->withCount('post_images')
  ->orderBy('post_images_count', 'desc')
  ->take(8)
  ->get();
```

After that I got this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::post_images()`

I did not understand what mistake is here.

Here `users table` has relation with `posts Table` and Posts table has relation with `post_images table`

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function postimages()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PostImage::class, Post::class);
}
```

Please guide How can I fix this.

Comment: You can make `User::with() / User::withCount()` only on related Models. And you dont have related User with post_images table. But you can make somthing like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681353/4771277

Comment: Please post your model's relationship code

Comment: @Autista_z I have already created this relation ship

Comment: @Jono20201 relationship code is updated

Comment: Shouldn't `withCount('post_images')` be `withCount('postimages')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @linktoahref said, `withCount` is taking a relation method names as argument, not a table nor a column name.

`withCount('postimages')`should fix your problem