# Load laravel eloquent model withCount of related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Given I have two eloquent models: Booking and Customer.

When I list all Bookings along with the respective Customer, I also want to show the amount of Bookings the respective customer has in total (count of this Booking + all other bookings).

Example output:

- Booking1: Customer A (has 20 Bookings total)
- Booking2: Customer B (has 10 Booking total)
- Booking3: Customer C (**VIP**: has 100 Bookings total)

In order to avoid the n+1 problem (one additional query per booking while showing this), I'd like to eager load the `bookingsCount` for the Customer.

The relations are:

Booking: `public function customer() { return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class) }`

Customer: `public function bookings() { return $this->hasMany(Booking::class) }`

**Example for querying the Bookings with eager loading**

Working, but without eager loading of the bookingsCount:

```
Booking::whereNotCancelled()->with('customer')->get();
```

Not working:

```
Booking::whereNotCancelled()->with('customer')->withCount('customer.bookings')->get();
```

I learned, that you cannot use `withCount` on fields of related models, but you can create a `hasManyThrough` relation and call `withCount` on that relation, e.g. `Booking::whereNotCancelled()->withCount('customerBookings');` ([see accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation)).

However: This doesn't work. I guess, it's because a Booking belongsTo a Customer and a Customer hasMany Bookings.

**Here's the hasManyThrough relation of class Booking**

```
public function customerBookings()
{
    // return the bookings of this booking's customer
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Booking::class, Customer::class);
}
```

**Here's the failing test for hasManyThrough**

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_has_a_relationship_to_the_customers_bookings()
{
    // Given we have a booking
    $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();
    // And this booking's customer has other bookings
    $other = factory(Booking::class,2)->create(['customer_id' => $booking->customer->id]);
    // Then we expect the booking to query all bookings of the customer
    $this->assertEquals(3, Booking::find($booking->id)->customerBookings()->count());
}
```

**Reported error**

```
no such column: customers.booking_id (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "bookings" inner join "customers" on "customers"."id" = "bookings"."customer_id" where "customers"."booking_id" = efe51792-2e9a-4ec0-ae9b-a52f33167b66)
```

No surprise. There is no such column `customer.booking_id`.

**The Question**

Is the intended behavior even possible in this case? If so, how would I eager load the booking's customer's total count of bookings?

Comment: Have you tried `Booking::->with(['customer' => function($q) {$q->withCount('bookings');}])->get();`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class)->withCount('bookings');
}

Booking::whereNotCancelled()->with('customer')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple solution. This worked perfectly well – and it's beautiful.