# Count relations that have a relation in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Using the Laravel Eloquent ORM system I have created the following models:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 */
class Category extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $category_id
 */
class Question extends Model
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $question_id
 */
class Answer extends Model {}
```

Now I am trying to eager load the following values:

1. All categories
2. The amount of questions per category
3. The amount of answered questions per category

I have solved both 1 and 2 using this code:

```
$categories = Category
    ::withCount('questions')
    ->get();

$vars = ['categories' => $categories];
```

For the third value I tried something like this (which does not work):

```
$categories = Category
    ::withCount(['questions', 'questions as answered_questions' => function ($query) {
        $query->select()
            ->from('answers')
            ->whereRaw('answers.question_id = questions.id');
    }])
    ->get();
```

How can I efficiently calculate the amount of questions having one or more answers?

Comment: this  may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation

Comment: @rkj Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not solve my problem. With the solution given there I could count the *amount of answers* instead of the *amount of questions with answers*.

Comment: what do you mean by amount of questions with answers ? you mean amount of questions that has at least one answer ?

Comment: @rkj Exactly, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `has`

> Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    function answers()
    {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Answer::class, Question::class);
    }
}
```

> Fetch data

```
$categories = Category::withCount('questions')->has('answers')->get();

foreach($categories as $category){
  $category->name." - ". $category->questions_count;
}
```

Here `questions_count` is total question that has at least one answer for that category

Comment: Doesn't `answers_count` now contain the *amount of answers* instead of *answered questions*?

Comment: `questions_count` is the number of question for that category which has at least one answered and `answers_count` is the total number of answered for all questions for that category

Comment: if you only need number of questions that has answer then remove the `answers` from `withCount`

Comment: Ah I see. I got confused about that part as I don't need the amount of answers indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad it helps you

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @rkj I found out about the `has` function. With that I was able to create the following solution:

```
$categories = Category
    ::withCount(['questions', 'questions as answered_questions' => function ($query) {
        $query->has('answers');
    }])
    ->get();
```

Now the `$category->questions_count` and `$category->answered_questions` are available to me, which is exactly what I need.