# Laravel Eloquent get count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

I am trying to get result with the below query but I found error

```php
$getAllRequirementRecord = Requirement::with('RequirementLocation')
    ->withCount('RequirementRecruiter')
    ->withcount('Interview.candidate')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Here is Error

> Call to undefined method
>   App\backend_model\Requirement\Requirement::Interview.candidate()

Comment: Does your `Interview` class has a candidate function?

Comment: there is a type in your code, ```withcount``` should be ```withCount```

Comment: @LucasPiazzi PHP isn't case sensitive for function names. Also, if it were, the error would be **undefined method withcount**.

Comment: I didn't say that was causing the problem, just pointed that he writed the same method in different style. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it will be execute successfully...

```
$getAllRequirementRecord = Requirement::with('RequirementLocation')->get();
foreach($getAllRequirementRecord as $a){
    $recruiter_count = RequirementRecruiter::select('agency_id','requirement_id')    
        ->where('requirement_id',$a->id)->distinct('agency_id')->count('agency_id');

    $candidate_count = CandidateReferance::select('candidate_id','requirement_id')
        ->where('requirement_id',$id)->distinct('candidate_id')enter code here
        ->count('candidate_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`withCount` looks for relationship methods on the model you are writing the query for, `Interview.candidate` doesn't look like a method name on the `Requirement` class.
If you are trying to navigate through the relationship `Requirement` -> `Interview` -> `Candidate` as [pointed on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation), you can define the following relationships on `Requirement`:

```php
function interview()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Interview::class);
}

function candidate()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Candidate::class, Interview::class);
}
```

And then:

```php
Tutorial::withCount(['interview', 'candidate'])
```

Comment: `withCount()` doesn't support nested relationships.

Comment: Thank you very muchas for pointing it out, I assumed it did. I'll edit my answer.