# laravel looping through eloquent models with deep relationships

Tags: laravel

The loop below works:

```
foreach($this->friends as $friend)
{
    foreach($friend->mailings as $mailing)
    {
        foreach($mailing->orders as $order)
        {
            $num_orders++;
        }

    }
}
```

But would like to do

```
foreach($this->friends->mailings->orders as $order)
{
    $num_orders++;
}
```

but when I do I get this error `Property [mailings] does not exist on this collection instance.`

The relationship between models is setup correctly (has many...etc)

Comment: Have you thought about Eager Loading in the data during your SQL query? That would then allow you to already have all the data from your relationships.

Comment: It's not possible to do it that way.  `friends` is a collection of friends, each friend has mailings, the entire collection doesn't have mailings and doesn't know what mailings is.

Comment: Laravel has support for nested relationship as well as you're able to define default results for if the relationship has no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I found it! Jarek is a great writer for Eloquent, and I wanted to see if he had a trick for this. As always he does. :)

```
$this->load(['friends.mailings.orders' => function($q) use(&$orders){
    $orders = $q->get();
}]);
```

Now if you `dd($orders)` you will have a list of all orders from mailings from friends related to `$this` So you can now foreach over that to get what you want.

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $num_orders++
}
```

His site has a certificate warning but this is where I got the above. 
https://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/

**Please ignore the below, as it is no longer needed but I'm keeping it here for clarity and because it was accepted as the answer.**

You can use the `each()` collection method to clean up your loops. Since there are many-to-many relationships you can't access the related models relations unless you iterate over them or specify which related item you want. See below:

```
$this->friends->each(function($friend, $key){
    $friend->each(function($mailing, $key2){
        $mailing->orders->each(function($orders, $key3){
            $num_orders++;
        })  
    });
})
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-each

There's also the `withCount()` query builder method that you may want to look into. It doesn't seem to like nested relations using the regular dot notation, but I haven't used it enough to say whether or not it can be used here. I stumbled upon [Laravel 5.3 withCount() nested relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation) while looking into the `withCount()` part. Seems like it may be possible but you will have to change your relations to `hasManyThrough()`. It should  be a good place to start.

Comment: Important to note how expensive this operation is on a large collection, since this is an n*2 operation.  If you have a collection of 100 items, you're performing 201 queries to get this data.   (One for the original get, one for each load, one for each get inside the closure).