# How to get an Eloquent collections of models from a model that has many degress of separation between the two?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have the following schema:

```
+------------+
| categories |
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+

+-------------+
| sections    |
+-------------+
| id          |
| category_id |
+-------------+

+------------+
| questions  |
+------------+
| id         |
| section_id |
+------------+

+------------+
| clients    |
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+

+-------------------+
| client_questions  |
+-------------------+
| client_id         |
| question_id       |
+-------------------+
```

As you can see questions are in sections and sections are in categories.

The admin of the system can toggle a question on or off for each individual client so I create client_questions to create the many-to-many relationship between clients and questions.

Now, I would like to harness the awesomeness of Eloquent to get a client's categories (to list out all the questions) but I can't seem to wrap my head around the query builder.

Basically I can currently do $client->questions via a many to many relationship I defined in the model:

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class,'client_questions','client_id','question_id');
}
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing between clients and categories considering the degree of separation.

Basically I would like to do `$client->categories` so that I can then list out the whole interview:

```
@foreach( $client->categories as $category)
  @foreach( $category->sections as $section)
    @foreach( $secion->questions as $question )
      {{ $question->question }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you have all the others relationships set up between the different models? Also, are you doing this for just one client?

Comment: I have the following relationships defined: question to section, section to category, client to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to define a direct relationship between `clients` and `categories`, however, you can use the existing relationships to get what you want.

For this I would suggest using a mixture of [with() (constrained eager loading)](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) and [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and starting with the `Category` model:

```
$categories = Category::with([
    'sections.questions.clients' => function ($query) use ($clientId) {
        $query->where('id', $clientId);
    },
])->whereHas('sections.questions.clients', function ($query) use ($clientId) {
    $query->where('id', $clientId);
})->get();
```

The reason you have to use both is because either one on their own could result in you having questions that don't directly relate to the client.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get it to work with your code out of the box -- though it made me realize that I was missing a relationship between questions and clients.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this at [laravel looping through eloquent models with deep relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798217/laravel-looping-through-eloquent-models-with-deep-relationships/55798461#55798461)

but basically you can use dot notation to load far reaching models onto the current one as long as they are all related down the chain.

```
$questions->load(['sections.categories' => function($q) use(&$categories){
    $categories = $q->get();
}]);
```

That should be all of the categories for the provided question.

Do note that this is an expensive operation so if the collection is too large be ready for a slog, but this is the only other way besides foreaching over foreaches that I've come across.

Comment: I already have a list of questions for the client via the client_questions table. Am I misunderstanding that your code gets me the questions based on the client category? I'm looking for the inverse, get categories from questions.

Comment: This can be used in any fashion as long as the models continue to have a relationship through the dots. I'll modify my answer to provide categories from questions.