# Laravel retrieve relationship data via another relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables

**Question** table:

```
id
title
description
```

**Answer** table:

```
id
answerbody
question_id
```

**Likes** table:

```
id
answer_id
```

I want to retrieve single question details with all the answers and answer_count and their respective likes (only like_count)

I tried this

```
public function show($id)
{
    return question::with(['answers','answers.likes'])->withCount(['answers'])->where('id',$id)- 
    >get();
}
```

How do I return likes with count?

Comment: have you defined your relations in your project?

Comment: yes,i have defined the relations.everything working fine.i just need the likes to be count.

Comment: It looks like this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation

Comment: Use [counting related model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I tried this-return question::with(['answers'])->withCount(['answers','likes'])->where('id',$id)->get();it throws a error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes.question_id'

Comment: @RaffianMoin yes and you have to define likes relationship in the question model using hasManyThrough as suggested in the answer in the link.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I did this- public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(answer::class, like::class);
    }

Comment: @RaffianMoin almost there, swap Answer::class and Like::class

Comment: @AnuratChapanond yes mate it worked.but it returns total likes of all the answers.i want like count of individual answers.how do i do that?

Comment: Oh well, you didn't mention it in the question though. I don't know how to do that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all answers for a question and along with their likes count you can call a closure inside your `with()` clause  and load their related likes count as

```
Question::with(['answers'=> function ($query) {
                $query->withCount('likes')
                      ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc');
        }])
        ->withCount(['answers'])
        ->where('id',$id)
        ->get();
```

This way you can also sort the answers based on their likes count

Comment: @RaffianMoin If it worked give you your expected result please accept this answer or take a time to go through [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Each question has many answers. So in the Question model add the below code :

```
public function answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

Each answer has many likes. So in the Answer model add the below code :

```
public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
```

Now you have to define a mutator "getDataAttribute" as below in the Question model:

```
public function getDataAttribute()
    {
        return [
            'question' => $this,
            'answers' => $this->answers()->get(),
            'answer_count' => $this->answers()->get()->count(),
            'likes' => $this->answers()->likes()->get(),
        ];
    }
```

Finally, anywhere you needed the question information you just need to invoke :

```
$question->data
```

to retrieve question, likes and question count.