# withExists() or withCount() for nested relationship (Many To Many and One To Many) in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have the following relationships in models:

Product.php

```
public function skus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sku::class);
}
```

Sku.php

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
}
```

I need to get an attribute indicating whether a product has at least one price or not (in the extreme case, just the number of prices).

```
Product::withExists('sku.prices') or Product::withCount('sku.prices')
```

I know about this repository https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through, but I prefer to use complex query once

UPDATE: I have already written a sql query for this purpose, but I don't know how to do it in Laravel:

```
SELECT
  *,
  EXISTS (SELECT
      *
    FROM prices
      INNER JOIN skus
        ON prices.sku_id = skus.id
      INNER JOIN product_sku
        ON skus.id = product_sku.sku_id
    WHERE products.id = product_sku.product_id
) AS prices_exists
FROM products
```

Comment: does `Product::withCount('sku.prices')` not giving you the expected results?

Comment: @rifqyabdl No. `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::skus.prices()'`

Comment: Try : Product::whereHas('sku.prices')

Comment: @YasinPatel, already tried, same error. Other questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633691/laravel-5-3-withcount-nested-relation) show that these methods (withExists() or withCount()) don't work directly with nested relationships

Comment: can you provide examples of the output value that you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get at least one record

```
$skuPrice = Sku::with('prices')
                ->has('prices', '>=', 1)
                ->withCount('prices')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not allow getting the number of prices for the product (not for the sku)